# python *args and **kwargs problems in calling sub-class methods from base-class

Tags: python, subclass, args, keyword-argument

I met a problem when I want to define a general run method in the base class, which call a method in the sub-class. The output shows that the kwargs in the get_run_string seems not correctly assigned by the kwargs in the method calling it.
Is there anything wrong with my codes? Thanks.

```
class Runnable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #self.computer=ComputingHost()
        pass
    def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
        cmd=self.get_run_string(args,kwargs)
        print kwargs
        #return cmd

def test_runnable():
    class Testr(Runnable):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Testr,self).__init__()
        def get_run_string(self,*args,**kwargs):
            print "in getrunstring ",args
            print "in getrunstring ",kwargs
            return 0
    a=Testr()
    a.run(x="aa",y="bb")

test_runnable()
```

Comment: What is the expected output? and what output do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in run you have to use

`cmd=self.get_run_string(*args, **kwargs)`.

Otherwise you just pass to 2 unnamed arguments and see both of them in args variable.

Comment: Yes. I found that the operator * and ** simply dissolve the list and dict data types into its context, is this correct to understand them?